# Apache as Reverse Proxy for CouchDB

Tags: http, proxy, erlang, apache2, couchdb

I'm thinking of a web app that uses CouchDB extensively, to the point where there would be great gains from serving with the native erlang HTTP API as much as possible.

Can you configure Apache as a reverse proxy to allow outside GETs to be proxied directly to CouchDB, whereas PUT/POST are sent to the application internal logic (for sanitation, authentication...)? Or is this unwise -- the CouchDB built-in authentication options just seem a little weak for a Web App.

Thanks

Comment: this is more of an apache question than a couchdb question. And the answer is I think no. There is no way to configure apache to proxy based on http method for the request. Christian's answer below is probably the best you will get.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to selectively proxy requests based on the HTTP method.

For example:

```
# Send all GET and HEAD requests to CouchDB
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET|HEAD
RewriteRule /db/(.*) http://localhost:5984/mydb/_design/myapp/$1 [P]

# Correct all outgoing Location headers
ProxyPassReverse /db/ http://localhost:5984/mydb/_design/myapp/
```

Any `POST`, `PUT`, or `DELETE` requests will be handled by Apache as usual, so you can wire up your application tier however you usually would.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is aging without answers, so I'll add this "almost answer".

[Nginx](http://nginx.net/) can definitely redirect differently based on requests.

This is, if you are ready to place nginx in the front as the revproxy and place apache and couchdb both as backends.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this? OAuth and cookie authentication were checked in on the 4th:

http://github.com/halorgium/couchdb/commit/335af7d2a9ce986f0fafa4ddac7fc1a9d43a8678

Also, if you're at all interested in using Erlang as the server language, you could proxy couchdb through webmachine:

http://blog.beerriot.com/2009/05/18/couchdb-proxy-webmachine-resource/

Answer (score -1):

I would consider using the reverse proxy feature of Apache mod_proxy. Create a virtual host configuraton that forwards certain HTTP requests of the web server to CouchDB. You can setup rules on which URI paths that should be forwarded etc.

See this guide for inspiration: http://macgyverdev.blogspot.se/2014/02/apache-web-server-as-reverse-proxy-and.html